# Using graphql.config.js and apollo.config.js with ApolloClient

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, apollo-client

How can I use graphql.config.js and apollo.config.js with ApolloClient? I want client to read graphql endpoint from the config file.

Also, is it possible to use graphql.config.js with Apollo VS Code extension?

Answer (score 0):

For the Apollo Client you need to pass the endpoint yourself as specified in the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/#create-a-client). But if you absolutely need to read the endpoint from a config file, I guess you could use the [cosmiconfig](https://github.com/davidtheclark/cosmiconfig) library to get the configuration values and pass them yourself to the client.

For the VSCode I do not think this is currently possible. The VS Code extension is using the [cosmiconfig](https://github.com/davidtheclark/cosmiconfig) library internally to load the configuration. The `module` name is [hard coded](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling/blob/3a5db49982fea1e6f29357ff122a82c1c92d6e27/packages/apollo-language-server/src/config/loadConfig.ts#L20) to `apollo`.